# Как написать DFA на C#

Tags: c#, конечные-автоматы

[image: Детерминированные конечные автоматы]

Как эту схему перевести в код? Это DFA (Детерминированные конечные автоматы)

Comment: вопрос стоит закрыть или править. разобрать невозможно.

Comment: вопрос стоит перевести на русский язык, а не писать транслитом.

Comment: @А К @Сергей Извините за транслитерацию просто у меня нет русской клавиатуры. Вопрос состоит в том чтобы перевезти схему на картинке в C# код. 001 это ошибка по токому сценарию не должен рабртать автомат.

Comment: DFA это deterministic finite automaton

Comment: @Сергей я все исправил. Приношу свои извинения.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Смотрите.

Для начала, вам нужно построить класс, описывающий состояние DFA. Что в нём есть? Список переходов, плюс признак того, заключительное ли это состояние.

Переходы проще всего кодировать словарём, отображающим символ входного алфавита на новое состояние. Символы входного алфавита закодируем как `char`.

Получаем:

```
class State
{
    public string Name;
    public Dictionary<char, State> Transitions;
    public bool IsAcceptState;
}
```

(я добавил ещё и имя, хотя оно по сути не нужно).

Вам нужно создать узлы, и связать их в таблицу состояний. Узлы будут наподобие такого:

```
State q4 = new State()
{
    Name = "Q4",
    IsAcceptState = false,
    Transitions = new Dictionary<char, State>()
    {
        ['0'] = q2 // если приходит 0, переходим в состояние q2
    }
};
```

(подумайте, как сделать так, чтобы первый узел мог ссылаться в таблице переходов на второй!)

Теперь, вам нужно определить класс для самого автомата, который содержит список состояний, и начальное состояние (это делайте сами, тут просто). Затем, что есть результат пробега DFA по строке? В конце мы либо оказываемся в финальном, либо в нефинальном состоянии. Ещё машина может остановиться, если перехода из какого-то состояние нет. Это удобно закодировать типом данных `bool?`.

Сам код пробега (*интерпретатор* конечного автомата) получается очень простым.

```
public bool? Run(IEnumerable<char> s)
{
    State current = InitialState;
    foreach (var c in s) // цикл по всем символам 
    {
        current = current.Transitions[c]; // меняем состояние на то, в которое у нас переход
        if (current == null)              // если его нет, возвращаем признак ошибки
            return null;
        // иначе переходим к следующему
    }
    return current.IsAcceptState;         // результат true если в конце финальное состояние 
}
```

Все части картины есть, собирайте!

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Полторы сотни прошли. Поздравляю )

Comment: @MansurMahmutov: Пожалуйста! Надеюсь, что помогло.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: И правда! Спасибо! :)